# WebStorm + Meteor in DEBUG mode. Memory leak + High CPU

Tags: debugging, meteor, memory-leaks, webstorm, cpu-usage

Every time I run a meteor project in debug mode and change a piece of code(from the server side), the server restarts and WebStorm's memory consumption increases greatly (never goes down again). After a few restarts the process gets unstable and the CPU consumption also goes crazy. Confirmed this on Windows  8 and 10, but seems to be happening in OSX too. (Happening since WebStorm 9, but with Meteor 1.3 things got much worse)

Before any answers, yes, I've checked and there's an open [JetBrains tracker Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20618), but since it has so little participation and no official answer, I was wondering if there's any workaround for this or it's just me and some few users getting this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it will be solved on the new EAP version. For now there's a workaround which consists in turning ON the button "Use Console Input"(last button on the console panel when Debug is running). For more details check the original issue [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20618)